# Get azure media service job progress in percentage

Tags: c#, azure-media-services

I am using azure media service .net SDK. I have uploaded video and try to encode it. I want encoding progress in percentage. Following code i use.

```
 string message = "Encoding percentage complete";
        double progress = 0;

        // encode status
        var job = _context.Jobs.Where(j => j.Name == jobName).FirstOrDefault();

        if (job != null)
        {
            var task = job.Tasks.FirstOrDefault();
            if (task != null && task.State != JobState.Error && task.State != JobState.Canceled && task.State != JobState.Canceling)
            {
                message = "Encoding video";
                progress = task.Progress;
            }
            else
            {
                message = task.State.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            message = "NotFound";
        }

        return new Tuple<string, double>(message, progress);
```

When above code gets executed, every time 0 return. Is there any way to get encoding status in percentage?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. I tested your code with a job that involved a long running job, and it reported progress correctly. Could you try running your jobs in https://aka.ms/amse and verify that you can see progress updated in the Jobs tab?  Otherwise please share sample Job IDs and the data center you are using, we can take a look at it.

Comment: @AnilMurching i have one question, if i am creating on job with trim and encode. trimming 5 min video to 1min and then encode, then how it's work encode 5min video first and then trim or trim to 1min and then encode?

Comment: I presume you are using a preset such as in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-advanced-encoding-with-mes#trim_video. In that case, the operations of trim and encode occur simultaneously.

Comment: @AnilMurching thanks for the information